# how to put rectangle for labeled images?? which is labeled using CC = bwconncomp(BW)

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I labeled an image using `CC = bwconncomp(BW);` and masking the label with maximum area using code

```
numPixels = cellfun(@numel,CC.PixelIdxList);
[biggest,idx] = max(numPixels);
BW(CC.PixelIdxList{idx}) = 0;
```

Now I want to put thin rectangular box around that maximum area instead of masking it. How it can be done?

**Full Code:**

```
f = imread('test.PNG');
subplot(2,2,1); imshow(f,[]); title('Original Image');
for i = 1:3 
    Image = medfilt2(Image,[3 3]);
end
[Image_Num, num] = bwlabel(Image,8);
subplot(2,2,3); imshow(Image); title('after median filtering'); %labeling algorithm
BW=im2bw(Image);
subplot(2,2,4); imshow(BW); title('binary image');
CC = bwconncomp(BW); %area based segmentation
numPixels = cellfun(@numel,CC.PixelIdxList);
[biggest,idx] = max(numPixels);
BW(CC.PixelIdxList{idx}) = 0;
figure;
imshow(BW); title('AFTER AREA BASED MASKING');
```

Comment: have you considered using `rectangle` annotation function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`bwlabel`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwlabel.html) with [`regionprops`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html) and [`rectangle`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rectangle.html) annotation:

```
 lb = bwlabel( bw ); %// label each CC
 st = regionprops( lb, 'Area', 'BoundingBox' ); %// get area and bounding box for each region
 [mxa mxi] = max( [st.Area] ); %// find max area region
```

Now you can annotate

```
 figure;
 imshow( bw ); hold on;
 rectangle('Position', st(mxi).BoundingBox, 'EdgeColor', 'r' );
```

On the `'coins.png'` image this results with:
[image]

Comment: what if there are two objects with same area then how it works?? because in my image i have two objects which have same area...when i masked them both get masked but when i used this code its putting rectangle for only one object...

Comment: @santoshpatil in that case, you'll need to use `find`: `mxi = find( [st.Area] == max([st.Area]) );` to get all indices of regions with area equal to max. The you call `rectangle` in a loop for each such region.

Answer (score 1):

`CC.PixelIdxList{idx}` will give you the linear indices of the locations in the image of where your object is located.

What you can do is use [`ind2sub`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html) to convert the linear indices to row and column locations, then we can determine the top left and bottom right corner of these row and column indices.  Once we do this, we can thus mark your image accordingly.

Therefore:

```
%// Determine row and column locations
[row,col] = ind2sub(size(BW), CC.PixelIdxList{idx});

%// Get top left and bottom right coordinates
topleft_row = min(row);
topleft_col = min(col);
bottomright_row = max(row);
bottomright_col = max(col);

%// Draw a white box around the object
%// Left vertical line
BW(topleft_row:bottomright_row, topleft_col) = true;
%// Right vertical line
BW(topleft_row:bottomright_row, bottomright_col) = true;
%// Top horizontal line
BW(topleft_row, topleft_col:bottomright_col) = true;
%// Bottom horizontal line
BW(bottomright_row, topleft_col:bottomright_col) = true;
```

---

Here's an example using `coins.png` that's built-in to MATLAB.  I read in the image, threshold it and fill in the holes.

```
im = imread('coins.png');
BW = im2bw(im, graythresh(im));
BW = imfill(O, 'holes');
```

When I do that and run the above code to draw a rectangle around the largest object, this is what I get:

[image]

---

Where this code ties into your program, **don't** do any masking.  Replace the masking code with the above... so:

```
f = imread('test.PNG');
subplot(2,2,1); imshow(f,[]); title('Original Image');
for i = 1:3 
    Image = medfilt2(Image,[3 3]);
end
[Image_Num, num] = bwlabel(Image,8);
subplot(2,2,3); imshow(Image); title('after median filtering'); %labeling algorithm
BW=im2bw(Image);
subplot(2,2,4); imshow(BW); title('binary image');
CC = bwconncomp(BW); %area based segmentation
numPixels = cellfun(@numel,CC.PixelIdxList);
[biggest,idx] = max(numPixels);

%-------- CHANGE HERE

%// Determine row and column locations
[row,col] = ind2sub(size(BW), CC.PixelIdxList{idx});

%// Get top left and bottom right coordinates
topleft_row = min(row);
topleft_col = min(col);
bottomright_row = max(row);
bottomright_col = max(col);

%// Draw a white box around the object
%// Left vertical line
BW(topleft_row:bottomright_row, topleft_col) = true;
%// Right vertical line
BW(topleft_row:bottomright_row, bottomright_col) = true;
%// Top horizontal line
BW(topleft_row, topleft_col:bottomright_col) = true;
%// Bottom horizontal line
BW(bottomright_row, topleft_col:bottomright_col) = true;
```

Comment: Well it worked for my example. I can't tell what you're doing wrong without all your code. Sorry. Good luck though!

Comment: here is my cmplte code 'f = imread('test.PNG');
subplot(2,2,1)
imshow(f,[]), title('Original Image')
for i = 1:3
Image = medfilt2(Image,[3 3]);
end
[Image_Num, num] = bwlabel(Image,8);
subplot(2,2,3);
imshow(Image);
title('after median filtering');


%labeling algorithm

BW=im2bw(Image);
subplot(2,2,4);
imshow(BW);
title('binary image');
CC = bwconncomp(BW);

%area based segmentation
 numPixels = cellfun(@numel,CC.PixelIdxList);
[biggest,idx] = max(numPixels);
BW(CC.PixelIdxList{idx}) = 0;
figure,imshow(BW);
title('AFTER AREA BASED MASKING');'

Comment: Update your post. Don't put it in a comment. Going to bed. Sorry!

Comment: @santoshpatil - I think I know what's going on.  You're still using your masking code to mask out the largest object.  Don't do that.  Replace that code with what I have above... it works for me.